# Permanently change the default Python3 version in Linux (Ubuntu on Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, wsl-2

I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu on Windows 11 v2004.2022.10 and I have both Python 3.8 and 3.9 installed. I want to make the 3.9 version the default, and I'm happy to remove Python 3.8 altogether if necessary.

If I type `python --version` in Ubuntu, I get `Python 3.8.10`.

I tried the following:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.9 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 0
```

and if I type `sudo update-alternatives --config python`

I see

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.9   1         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.8   0         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.9   1         manual mode
```

However, if I type again python3 --version, it still says `Python 3.8.10`

I then tried `sudo update-alternatives --remove python /usr/bin/python3.8` and now `sudo update-alternatives --config python` tells me that `There is only one alternative in link group python (providing /usr/bin/python): /usr/bin/python3.9 Nothing to configure.`

And yet, `python3 --version` still says `Python 3.8.10`

I also tried sudo `update-alternatives  --set python /usr/bin/python3.9` and that didn't work either.

This works: `alias python='/usr/bin/python3.9'`: now `python3 --version` is `Python 3.9.5` - but only temporarily, as upon closing and reopening Ubuntu it reverts to Python 3.8.10.

I then tried creating a permanent alias by adding that same line to my .bashrc script (I followed [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soi7Urg3KZI) steps), and the same thing happened.

I'm new to all of this, so please be patient.

How can I change the default Python 3.8 to the 3.9 version, and/or remove Python 3.8 altogether? I tried deleting the python3.8 directory but that didn't work. Perhaps it's because I still have python3.8-config, which I didn't manage to delete?

Thanks!

Comment: `python3` and `python` need not be the same thing.  You seem to be mixing them at random.   You can see what each links to by doing `ls -l /usr/bin/python*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use
`sudo update-alternatives --config python3`
and then select your python3 version.
That should solve your issue without needing to do weird configs.

Comment: It just gives "update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python" after apt-get install python3.9.. something else is required I guess..

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it!
I had to do add `alias python3='/usr/bin/python3.9'` in my `~/.bash_aliases` file (or you can add it directly in `~/.bash_rc`) with no spaces, and including the number 3, to my bash script, following the video I linked above. And then I had to close and re-open the terminal - typing `clear` was not enough.

I'd love to hear some explanations on why the `sudo update-alternatives` commands didn't work though!

Comment: I would too. -alter... doesn't work on my system even though the star is again the version I want.  Is this why no one uses Linux on desktops?

Comment: Where did you added this? Please edit you answer to show a fully functional solution if possible. Thank you